# MIPS architecture

Tags: assembly, mips

```
li $v0,5 
syscall
la $t2,0($v0)
```

I couldn't understand that code(or entire subject). when I run this $t2 is holding the value that ı gave as an input
but does it should hold the address of v0[0] ? Because 'la' put the address into a register.
why lw instruction doesn't work for this code ?

Comment: Syscall #5 is read integer, it returns a value in $v0 not an address. `la $t2, 0($v0)` is just a convoluted way to say `move $t2, $v0`. `lw` does not work because there is no memory involved.

Comment: Some docs here: http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html

Comment: Most CPUs have sets of what we call pseudo instructions which disassembler do not always try to replicate and thus you may see _weird_ instructions as a result when looking at existing code. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Pseudoinstructions